# How to check the blobstorage in Plone/ZODB?

Tags: plone

My HDD has failed and some inodes were fixed, i.e

```
'..' in /zeocluster/var/blobstorage/0x00/0x00 (...) is <the NULL inode> (0), should be '....'.  Fix (y) ?
```

How do I confirm things are still ok. Is there something like a `blobfsck` for ZODB/Plone?

--

Re-posted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895033/how-to-check-the-blobstorage-in-plone-zodb

Comment: This was also closed in stackoverflow.com cause they deem is not a software question... Which would be the forum to post this kind of question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like. Try out [zc.zodbdgc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.zodbdgc):

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.zodbdgc
- http://zodborg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/articles/multi-zodb-gc.html

It provides a script, which can check that all referenced objects including all blobs still exist. Yet, it cannot verify that the blob contents are ok (it alerts on missing blob files, but will silently accept empty/corrupted but still existing blob files).

The documentation shows how to include it in buildout

```
[buildout]
parts =
    ...
    zodbdgc

[zodbdgc]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = zc.zodbdgc
```

and what kind of configuration file it requires – it won't accept your `parts/instance/zope.conf` directly, but you can copy and strip down a version that only includes

```
<zodb main>  # renamed from zodb_db main
  <blobstorage>
    blob-dir /.../var/blobstorage
    # FileStorage database
    <filestorage>
      path /.../var/filestorage/Data.fs
    </filestorage>
  </blobstorage>
</zodb>
```

and then run

```
./bin/multi-zodb-check-refs parts/instance/copy_of_zope.conf
```

and if there's a blob missing, you will see something like

```
!!! main 4938 ?
POSKeyError: 'No blob file'
```

and the documentation may help you to fix the issue manually.